# Make a FFmpeg thumbnail?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I'm kind of new with FFmpeg but as a project to learn some mysql databasing I'm trying to create a video upload site.

When I try to make a thumbnail with this code:

shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i anim.flv -an -ss 00:00:03 -an -r 1 -vframes 1 -y test.jpg");

nothing happens, no image appear in the same directory as the anim.flv, is there something wrong with the code or what could the problem be?

Comment: What does `shell_exec` returns. Did you try running the command directly in shell once? if yes, What was your result?

Comment: When I use the code right now nothing appears on the site. As i said I'm not very good with FFmpeg but I used some script that should return if FFmpeg was installed on the server and it appeared positive, so i don't really know what the problem could be.

Comment: You are not getting me. you are new it is okay, everyone is new for the technologies because those are updated very frequently. What I mean is you must try your FFMPEG command at least once in your shell directly, so you get to know what exactly is happening, what error you are message your are getting.

Comment: I got it to work now! Finally after quite some research i found out myself that the problem was that i had not set the permissions properly. Thanks for the fast respons anyway!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me: `ffmpeg -ss 00:00:10 -i $file -y -an -vframes 1 $dir/$name.png`

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
$infile = 'anim.flv';
$outfile = 'test.jpg';
exec("/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i " . escapeshellarg($infile) . " -an -ss 00:00:03 -an -r 1 -vframes 1 -y " . escapeshellarg($outfile) . " 2>&1", $output, $returnValue);
if (!file_exists($outfile)) {
     die("Could not generate thumbnail. ffmpeg output: \n\n" . implode("\n", $output));
}
```

This way you will get some detailed output from ffmpeg when it doesn't work (the "2>&1"  redirects ffmpeg's error output to stdout; otherwise you would not be able to retrieve it).

I have 2 suggestions that might fix your command; first, add the arguments "-vcodec mjpeg -f rawvideo" before specifying the output file, and second, use absolute paths for the input and output, so you don't have to worry about where your script's current working directory is.

Comment: I get the return: Could not generate thumbnail. ffmpeg output: Array

Comment: I did set it to the paths /home/albin/www/test.jpg and /home/albin/www/anim.flv and it still do not work

Comment: Sorry about that, I forget that $output is an array of lines, not just one big string. Change it to: die("Could not generate thumbnail. ffmpeg output: \n\n" . implode("\n", $output)); and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the response but i found out now that the problem was as simple as i had set the permissions wrong. Sorry for my bad english, thanks anyway!

Comment: @JonathanAmend If you have a time can you check my ffmpeg problem question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54178375/php-video-upload-and-ffmpeg-wont-create-a-thumbnail

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$flvfile = 'clock.flv';
$imagefile = 'test.jpg';
exec('ffmpeg  -i ' . $flvfile . ' -f mjpeg -vframes 1 -s 150x150 -an ' . $imagefile . '');
```