# How does Youtube dissects frames from videos?

Tags: youtube-api

How does Youtube dissects frames from videos?

Is there any way we can get the frames extracted from each video from some youtube api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit unclear on your question -

If you mean can you get some thumbnail images from actual YouTube videos, then the answer is yes. Please see the post here: [How do I get a YouTube video thumbnail from the YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-to-get-thumbnail-of-youtube-video-link-using-youtube-api)

If you mean that you have some videos locally on your machine and you want to extract some thumbnails from them (similar to the way YouTube does), then that's easy too. Just use ffmpeg: [Make a FFmpeg thumbnail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398842/make-a-ffmpeg-thumbnail)