# php video upload and ffmpeg won't create a thumbnail

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am trying to make a video upload feature for my project. But I have a problem with **ffmpeg** section. **ffmpeg** is already installed on my server. But i can not get any thumbnail. I have try to create thumbnail using the following code:

```
$videoa = exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg  -i $videoUrlp.flv -f flv -s 650x390 $videoUrlp.mp4 2>&1");
$videob = exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg  -i $videoUrlp.mp4 -vcodec png -ss 00:00:5 -s 650x390 -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo $videoUrlp.png");
```

But i ge this when use `var_dump();` for `var_dump($videoa);` and `var_dump($videob);`

> string(74) "https://mywebsite.com/uploads/video/ey1kXNew_video.flv:
>   Input/output error" string(0) ""

Also if i use the `shell_exec` like this:

```
$videoa = shell_exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg  -i $videoUrlp.flv -f flv -s 650x390 $videoUrlp.mp4");
$videob = shell_exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg  -i $videoUrlp.mp4 -vcodec png -ss 00:00:5 -s 650x390 -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo $videoUrlp.png");
```

and the `var_dumps()` giving me `NULL` `NULL`.

Please help me where am I wrong.

And here is my full video upload code:

```
$valid_formats = array("mp4","MP4","flv");
            if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
               $name = $_FILES['uploading']['name'];
               $size = $_FILES['uploading']['size'];
               if(strlen($name)) {
                   $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); 
                   $name = alphaID(microtime(true) * 10000).'_video';
                   if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats)) {
                   if($size<(50024*50024)) {
                      $GetVideoName = $name;
                      $video_ext=$ext;
                       $tmp = $_FILES['uploading']['tmp_name'];
                       if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $videoPath.$GetVideoName.'.'.$video_ext)) {
                           $videoUrlp = $base_url.'uploads/video/'.$GetVideoName;
                           $videoa = exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg  -i $videoUrlp.flv -f flv -s 650x390 $videoUrlp.mp4 2>&1");
                           $videob = exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg  -i $videoUrlp.mp4 -vcodec png -ss 00:00:5 -s 650x390 -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo $videoUrlp.png");
                           echo var_dump($videoa);
                           echo var_dump($videob);

                        } else {
                            echo "Fail upload folder with read access.";
                        }
                     } else
                        echo "Image file size max 1 MB";                    
                     } else
                        echo "invalidvieo"; 
                 } else
                    echo "Please select image..!";
                 exit;
              }
```

I have tested also like this way:

```
echo exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i $videoUrlp.flv -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f flv -s 780x400 $videoUrlp.$video_ext");
echo exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i $videoUrlp.$video_ext -deinterlace -an -ss 1 -t 00:00:05 -r 1 -y -vcodec mjpeg -f mjpeg $videoUrlp.png 2>&1");
```

and I see the following echo

**`video:71kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000000%`**

and another try then I get this note: *https://mywebsite.com/uploads/video/1547892356_video.flv: Connection refused*

```
echo exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i $videoUrlp.flv -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f flv -s 780x400 $videoUrlp.$video_ext");
echo exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i $videoUrlp.$video_ext -deinterlace -an -ss 1 -t 00:00:05 -r 1 -y -vcodec mjpeg -f mjpeg $videoUrlp.png 2>&1");
```

Here is last shell_exec Output:

```
 $local = 'https://website.com/uploads/video/'.$GetVideoName.'.'.$video_ext;
 $localTumb = 'https://website.com/uploads/video/'.$GetVideoName.'.png';
 echo shell_exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i $local -deinterlace -an -ss 1 -t 00:00:05 -r 1 -y -vcodec mjpeg -f mjpeg $localTumb 2>&1");
```

> ffmpeg version 2.8.15 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)
>   configuration:   --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin
>   --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg    --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg    --libdir=/usr/lib64    --mandir=/usr/share/man    --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro '    --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libcdio --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-nonfree --disable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openal --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect libavutil 54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100 libavcodec 56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100    libavformat 56. 40.101 / 56.
>   40.101 libavdevice 56. 4.100 / 56. 4.100    libavfilter 5. 40.101 / 5. 40.101 libavresample 2. 1. 0 / 2. 1. 0    libswscale 3. 1.101 / 3. 1.101 libswresample 1. 2.101 / 1. 2.101    libpostproc 53. 3.100 / 53. 3.100 Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'https://website.com/uploads/video/e0J6HwtK_video.mp4': Metadata:
>   major_brand : mp42 minor_version : 0 compatible_brands: isommp42
>   creation_time : 2018-01-01 12:09:49 Duration: 00:00:41.49, start:
>   0.000000, bitrate: 230 kb/s Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 240x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 2:3], 158
>   kb/s, 9.73 fps, 9.73 tbr, 19462 tbn, 19.46 tbc (default) Metadata:
>   handler_name : VideoHandler Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a /
>   0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 71 kb/s (default) Metadata:
>   creation_time : 2018-01-01 12:09:49 handler_name : IsoMedia File
>   Produced by Google, 5-11-2011 [swscaler @ 0xc8c580] deprecated pixel
>   format used, make sure you did set range correctly Output #0, mjpeg,
>   to 'https://website.com/uploads/video/e0J6HwtK_video.png': Metadata:
>   major_brand : mp42 minor_version : 0 compatible_brands: isommp42
>   encoder : Lavf56.40.101 Stream #0:0(und): Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc),
>   240x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 2:3], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 1 fps, 1 tbn, 1 tbc
>   (default) Metadata: handler_name : VideoHandler encoder :
>   Lavc56.60.100 mjpeg Stream mapping: Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native)
>   -> mjpeg (native)) Press [q] to stop, [?] for help frame= 5 fps=0.0 q=1.6 Lsize= 100kB time=00:00:05.00 bitrate= 163.9kbits/s dup=0
>   drop=32 video:100kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global
>   headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000000%

Comment: What if you run the FFMPEG command in shell? Also, to create an [MCV example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you can first try to run this in a new PHP: `var_dump(exec('/usr/bin/ffmpeg -version'));`

Comment: @Raptor The print like this: `string(38) "libpostproc 53. 3.100 / 53. 3.100" `

Comment: @Raptor `shell_exec` giving mie `NULL` `NULL` in `var_dump();`

Comment: If the 1-line example is able to give valid output (just like you just tested), the problem only lies in the FFMPEG command itself. Try to run it directly in shell, instead via PHP.

Comment: @Raptor What do you mean with `directly in shell` ?

Comment: Run in your computer / server. Use your Terminal / Shell Console in your Linux-based machine. Is it a Mac or Linux?

Comment: @Raptor I am trying it online server. It is linux but i don't know how to use terminal in online server.

Comment: @Azzo Your host probably has instructions on how to use `ssh` to log into your server. Without trying `ffmpeg` directly and unscripted in a command-line interface then we can only guess and not make any actual answers.

Comment: @llogan Here is the print from ssh : https://prnt.sc/m74ztc can you check it for me please. maybe this will help

Comment: From your latest update of information, your FFMPEG command is actually running. You should note that `exec()` only returns the last line from the result. Also, you should note that your second command contains `2>&1` at the end, which redirects the output elsewhere. If I were you, I will redirect the output to a log file. And you parse the log file some time later.

Comment: To do so, you can modify your second command to: `/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i $videoUrlp.$video_ext -deinterlace -an -ss 1 -t 00:00:05 -r 1 -y -vcodec mjpeg -f mjpeg $videoUrlp.png > /path/to/your/log/file.log 2>&1`

Comment: I have done something similar before, but I was using cronjob instead. The cronjob monitors a folder for new file, and handle it once found. The whole process is logged and automated, i.e. no need to run the PHP to execute the command, which avoid problems like browser timeout, network timeout, half-finished tasks, etc.

Comment: Apparently you are attempting to output to `https://mywebsite.com/uploads/video/`. How is that supposed to work? You can't arbitrarily output to a server without any credentials. If the server that is running ffmpeg is the same one hosting the site you want to output to then use local paths, and not via HTTPS protocol.

Comment: @llogan Can you explain it via code please ?

Comment: @Azzo No, because I'm not sure if the same server is being used to both host the site and run ffmpeg.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using https, your ffmpeg has to be configured with ssl support ([ffmpeg over https fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31514949/ffmpeg-over-https-fails)).

Answer (score 5):

arguments have to be escaped, you can't just dump variables in there as arguments, urls contain stuff like `&` which has special meaning in shells.. for example this

> exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg  -i $videoUrlp.flv -f flv -s 650x390 $videoUrlp.mp4 2>&1");

should have been this:

> exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg  -i ".escapeshellarg($videoUrlp.flv)." -f flv -s 650x390 ".escapeshellarg($videoUrlp.mp4)." 2>&1");

but..

> please anyone can help me?

here are 2 functions to get the thumbnail, getThumbPng2() will download the entire video first with curl, saving it to a temporary file, and then extract the url with ffmpeg (this is safer if ffmpeg isn't built with http/https/whatever support, or if ffmpeg is blocked by a firewall or whatever, but the downside is that it's potentially much slower)

and the first function fetches the thumbnail from ffmpeg without fetching the video first (which is potentially much faster as ffmpeg will just read the required parts instead of downloading the entire video, but may not work for reasons explained above)

```
function getThumbPng2(string $uri, string &$imageBinary=NULL, string &$stderr=NULL):bool{
    $ch=curl_init($uri);
    if(!$ch){
        $imageBinary=$stderr="curl_init() failed";
        return false;
    }
    $tmph=tmpfile();
    curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=>false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=>false,
        CURLOPT_FILE=>$tmph
    ));
    if(!curl_exec($ch)){
        $imageBinary=$stderr="curl error: ".curl_errno($ch).": ".curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        fclose($tmph);
        return false;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    $ret=getThumbPng(stream_get_meta_data($tmph)['uri'],$imageBinary,$stderr);
    fclose($tmph);
    return $ret;
}
function getThumbPng(string $uri,string &$imageBinary=NULL, string &$stderr=NULL):bool{
    $imageBinary="";
    $stderr="";
    $descriptorspec = array(
        0 => array("pipe", "rb"),  // stdin
        1 => array("pipe", "wb"),  // stdout
        2 => array("pipe","wb") // stderr 
    );
    $cmd="ffmpeg -i ".escapeshellarg($uri)." -ss 00:00:3 -s 650x390 -vframes 1 -c:v png -f image2pipe -";
    // var_dump($cmd);
    $proc = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes);
    if(!$proc){
        $stderr="failed to start ffmpeg, proc_open(\"ffmpeg\",...) failed. (why? don't know, and PHP has no way of telling us either, afaik.)";
        return false;
    }
    fclose($pipes[0]);// by default stdin is *inherited*, which is not what we want,
    // so to avoid the default behaviour, we explicitly create a stdin pipe and close it.
    $fetch=function()use(&$pipes,&$imageBinary,&$stderr){
        $tmp=stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
        if(is_string($tmp)){
            $imageBinary.=$tmp;
        }
        $tmp=stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
        if(is_string($tmp)){
            $stderr.=$tmp;
        }   
    };
    while(($status=proc_get_status($proc))['running']){
        usleep(10*1000);
        $fetch();
    }
    $fetch();
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);
    $ret=$status['exitcode'];
    proc_close($proc);
    //var_dump($ret);
    return ($ret===0);
}
```

example usage:

```
<?php
if(getThumbPng("http://files.4x4norway.no/2018/vik2.webm",$imageBinary,$stderr)){
    echo "got a thumbnail! (the png binary data is in the \$imageBinary variable.)";
}else{
    var_dump($imageBinary);
    echo "failed to create thumbnail! error: {$stderr}";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use this code:
`
          //thumb path should be added in the below code
          //test for thumb

```
      $dir_img='uploads/';
      $mediapath='123.jpg';

      $file_thumb=create_movie_thumb($dir_img.$mediapath,$mediapath,$mediaid);

        $name_file=explode(".",$mediapath);
        $imgname="thumb_".$name_file[0].".jpg";     



        /*
          Function to create video thumbnail using ffmpeg
        */
        function create_movie_thumb($src_file,$mediapath,$mediaid)
        {
            global $CONFIG, $ERROR;

            $CONFIG['ffmpeg_path'] = '/usr/local/bin/'; // Change the path according to your server.
            $dir_img='uploads/';
            $CONFIG['fullpath'] = $dir_img."thumbs/";

            $src_file = $src_file;
            $name_file=explode(".",$mediapath);
            $imgname="thumb_".$name_file[0].".jpg";
            $dest_file = $CONFIG['fullpath'].$imgname;

            if (preg_match("#[A-Z]:|\\\\#Ai", __FILE__)) {
                // get the basedir, remove '/include'
                $cur_dir = substr(dirname(__FILE__), 0, -8);
                $src_file = '"' . $cur_dir . '\\' . strtr($src_file, '/', '\\') . '"';
                $ff_dest_file = '"' . $cur_dir . '\\' . strtr($dest_file, '/', '\\') . '"';
            } else {
                $src_file = escapeshellarg($src_file);
                $ff_dest_file = escapeshellarg($dest_file);
            }

            $output = array();

            if (eregi("win",$_ENV['OS'])) {
                // Command to create video thumb
                $cmd = "\"".str_replace("\\","/", $CONFIG['ffmpeg_path'])."ffmpeg\" -i ".str_replace("\\","/" ,$src_file )." -an -ss 00:00:05 -r 1 -vframes 1 -y ".str_replace("\\","/" ,$ff_dest_file);
                exec ("\"$cmd\"", $output, $retval);

            } else {
                // Command to create video thumb
                $cmd = "{$CONFIG['ffmpeg_path']}ffmpeg -i $src_file -an -ss 00:00:05 -r 1 -vframes 1 -y $ff_dest_file";
                exec ($cmd, $output, $retval);

            }


            if ($retval) {
                $ERROR = "Error executing FFmpeg - Return value: $retval";
                if ($CONFIG['debug_mode']) {
                    // Re-execute the command with the backtick operator in order to get all outputs
                    // will not work if safe mode is enabled
                    $output = `$cmd 2>&1`;
                    $ERROR .= "<br /><br /><div align=\"left\">Cmd line : <br /><span style=\"font-size:120%\">" . nl2br(htmlspecialchars($cmd)) . "</span></div>";
                    $ERROR .= "<br /><br /><div align=\"left\">The ffmpeg program said:<br /><span style=\"font-size:120%\">";
                    $ERROR .= nl2br(htmlspecialchars($output));
                    $ERROR .= "</span></div>";
                }
                @unlink($dest_file);
                return false;
            }

            $return = $dest_file;
            //@chmod($return, octdec($CONFIG['default_file_mode'])); //silence the output in case chmod is disabled
            return $return;
        }`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check ffmpeg installed file on your server.

```
$ffmpeg = trim(shell_exec('whereis ffmpeg')); // This will show you which path FFMPEG 

if (empty($ffmpeg))
{
    die('ffmpeg not available');
}else{
    echo $ffmpeg;
}
```

Then try this:

```
$cmd = shell_exec("$ffmpeg -i $videoUrlp.mp4 -ss 00:00:02.000 -vframes 1 $videoUrlp.png");
```

---